# Cannot make post in Article when I add belongs_to :user to /app/models/article.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I went through the Rails tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and created an articles model.  I didn't add the comments part to my application.  I set up Devise to handle users.

That worked well and users could create, edit, and destroy each other posts.  I now want to allow users to only edit or delete their own article posts.

I made some changes and I am getting an error "User must exist" when any user tries to create an article post.  I noticed that adding belongs_to :user is what is creating this error.  Is there a way to fix this?

I added a reference and foreign key with:

```
rails g migration AddUserToUploads user:references
```

I then made sure I migrated this:

```
class AddUserToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :articles, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

I added 'belongs_to :user' to app/models/article.rb so it looks like:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }

  belongs_to :user

end
```

My app/models/user.rb looks like this now:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :lockable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :articles
end
```

I temporarily disabled any user restrictions in my views.

My articles_controller.rb is set up like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    if params[:search]
      @articles = Article.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @articles = Article.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :description, :keyword, :syntax, :programlang)
    end
```

I have tried changing the destroy method to this but it still doesn't do anything:

```
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if user_signed_in? && current_user.articles.exists?(@article.id)
      @article.destroy
    else
      redirect_to articles_path
    end
  end
```

Am I missing something?  What changes do I need to make to my article?

Comment: Can your users create an article without being logged in?

Comment: No, I still have something things restricted.  Devise is handling authentication.  I figured out that the problem occurs when I add belongs_to :user.

Comment: you added the reference in `Upload` while you are trying to maintain an association in `Article`. Does your `article` actually has user_id field?

Comment: Fixed.  I typed the wrong word.

Comment: Stephane, do I need to adjust something in my create method then?

Comment: Are you passing the `user_id` via form for `create` action? I would have used `@article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)` instead of `@article = Article.new(article_params)`

Comment: Also, your `article_params` doesn't whitelist `user_id`. So even if it's passed, it would have been ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having multiple `before_action`s on top of your controller like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post,         only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :check_post_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    # just leave this blank - it's fine
  end

  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def check_post_owner
    if @article.user != current_user
      flash[:notice] = "You're not the owner"
      redirect_to articles_path
    end
  end

end
```

`:authenticate_user!` is Devise method. `set_post` and `check_post_owner` are custom methods inside the `private` section.

You also can refactor `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` line by creating a method and call it from `before_action` like inside my `set_post` method.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 you need to add required = false to your child model to allow creating child records when you are not creating child records via association methods

```
 class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }

  belongs_to :user, required: false

 end
```

Cheers!